# Unable to use Perl join properly to append something to each occurrence - getting "Array found where operator expected at" error

Tags: perl

I have log lines like these -

```
/mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-21.log.gz:2019-08-21 07:31:14,153 5458142 [XNIO-3 task-4] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.ws.FileManger [FileName.java:1838] - UUIDs in this bucket 8501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
/mnt/internal-app/logs/internal-app.log_2019-08-21.log.gz:2019-08-21 07:31:14,153 5458144 [XNIO-3 task-4] INFO  c.c.p.i.m.ws.FileManger [FileName.java:1838] - UUIDs in this bucket 6501792126581991569,8073766106536916628,4830289023695906800,6135982080116553120,8306484440313978157,9040948912536460872,8471856544054164043,5431263453539111247,7661719762428556576
```

I am using perl in output of cat to grab the UUIDs and wrap each of them in double quotes -

```
cat eligible_uuids_final_app1.txt | perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){@uuids=split(/,/); print "," , join ",",map{qq/"$_"/} @uuids; }'
```

Getting -

```
"9556896620363267700","7159125371810704365"
```

I further want to wrap each of these in first brackets. I am not a perl expert, but was able to add the starting bracket -

```
cat eligible_uuids_final_app1.txt | perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){@uuids=split(/,/); print "," , join ",(",map{qq/"$_"/} @uuids; }'
```

Getting -

```
("9556896620363267700",("7159125371810704365"
```

Trying to add the trailing bracket -

```
cat eligible_uuids_final_app1.txt | perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){@uuids=split(/,/); print "," , join ",(",map{qq/"$_"/}, join ,")" @uuids;  }'
```

Getting syntax error -

```
$ cat eligible_uuids_final_app1.txt | perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //){@uuids=split(/,/); print "," , join ",(",map{qq/"$_"/}, join ,")" @uuids;  }'
Array found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "")" "
    (Missing operator before  ?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "},"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: No need to use `cat` when `<` is perfectly good!

Comment: I'm not clear what output you want exactly - can't you just replace `map{qq/"$_"/}` by `map{qq/"($_)"/}`

Comment: Ah it was easy. @steeldriver please add as an answer.

Comment: @SandeepanNath ok done thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *each* element to be enclosed in parentheses as well as quotes, then you can simply add those to the existing `map` block i.e. replace

```
map{qq/"$_"/}
```

by

```
map{qq/"($_)"/}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to join the array elements by `(,` - that would put `(,` between every element of `@uuids`.

You just need to print a `(` before the join and an `)` after it.

For example, using `printf`:

```
$ perl -ne '
  chomp;
  if(s/^.*UUIDs in this bucket //) {
    @uuids=split(/,/);
    printf ",(%s)", join ",",map{qq/"$_"/} @uuids;
  }' eligible_uuids_final_app1.txt
,("8501792126581991569","8073766106536916628","4830289023695906800","6135982080116553120","8306484440313978157","9040948912536460872","8471856544054164043","5431263453539111247","7661719762428556576"),("6501792126581991569","8073766106536916628","4830289023695906800","6135982080116553120","8306484440313978157","9040948912536460872","8471856544054164043","5431263453539111247","7661719762428556576")
```

(linefeeds added to one-liner to make it readable)

I'm not sure if you wanted the leading comma inside the `(...)` or outside it.  I've assumed the former.  Adjust the printf format string as required.

You might want to add a newline (e.g. `printf ",(%s)\n", ....;`).